# "erstellen" or "erzeugen"?

Tags: translation, meaning, english-to-german

Software X is producing printed reports, based on user input. How would I translate accurately 'produced with X' and 'produced by X', as both *erstellen* and *erzeugen* seem to be very near in their meaning:

1. Mit X erstellt
2. Mit X erzeugt

What is the better translation for 'produced with' and 'produced by'? What are the subtle nuances?

Or maybe I am missing some other, better translation?

Comment: generiert, erstellt, erzeugt, produziert where from first to last the focus is changing from mental performance to machine productivity ....

Comment: @bummi: thank you for your reply -- you should however use the 'answer' button, not the 'comment' link for your answer to get a better visibility. This is how the StackExchange sites work.

Comment: a answer would have to be more founded IMHO

Comment: I could have up-voted it ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To me, *erzeugen* implies a slightly more thorough involvement than *erstellen.* Corresponding English translations that preserve this nuance would be *erzeugen → create* and *erstellen → compile.* The former implies the product is made from a much more basic input. For example, you would never use *erzeugen* in the context of building a physical object and you would never use *erstellen* in the context of biological creation (e.g., babies). (Note, however, that either word is rarely used in these example context and usually an altogether different word is used.)

In your specific context, I would use *erstellen* if the program only compiles some source data (which seems to be the case), while I would use *erzeugen* if the program actually generates the data. For example, for a random number generator, I would use *erzeugen,* while for a plotting program, I would use *erstellen.*

The authors of the Duden support my perception: [erstellen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erstellen), [erzeugen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erzeugen). Keep in mind, that all this is only a nuance, and both versions are most likely to be understood as intended.

PS: If you want to emphasize that the software only compiles the data, you might consider using *zusammenstellen.*

Comment: Thank you! From your explanation, I'll probably settle to 'Mit Crésus Lohnbuchhaltung 10.0.067 erzeugt', since the program does some complex calculations based on the original user input.

Comment: Fascinatingly, I would prefer *erstellt* in your context of accountancy, while *erzeugt* slightly implicates that the program also helped to generate the raw data. But as already stated, this is only a nuance.

Comment: The verb used in German for the tasks of creating lists, overviews, reports, balance sheets, etc. is usually 'erstellen' (in a more narrow context zusammenstellen=assemble/compile). Eine Lohnabrechnung erstellen, eine Kontenübersicht erstellen, eine Bilanz erstellen (or aufstellen), … The term 'erzeugen' would be closer to computer lingo referring to the technical process of generating computer-based objects (files, computer graphics, object code).

Comment: I agree with Wrzlprmtf... erstellen is what I would recommend and it matches up with the explanation since the program transforms input and it doesn't really create (as the great example "random number generator" would)

Comment: Thank you for the discussion. I think that I now better get the subtle difference. So it should be ... erstellt -- but is this true even if the program has to do possibly complicated computations to conform with Swiss law?

Comment: I would say, that the complexity of the action does not matter, but only the “originality“ (in lack of a better term) of the product.

Comment: I also agree with Wrzlprmft. IMO *erzeugen* is the better choice for tangible products while *erstellen* is better for intangible products.