# Difference between Erzeugen vs Erstellen vs Erschaffen

Tags: meaning, word-choice

This post explains to me the difference between [first two](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6452/erstellen-or-erzeugen) but could someone explain the difference between third and first two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These words are mostly synonym, but not completely

- erzeugen: to create something. This notably is the only verb of the three which can be applied to agricultural goods. Unless you apply genetic engineering on a molecular level to assemble the cells, one does not use 'erstellen' or 'erschaffen' in terms of anything living. This also applies often to other 'natural processes', like where something is generated, like in power generation ("Strom erzeugen"), or waste gas generation ("Abgaserzeugung"). Maybe one can say that this word is preferably used when you aid the creation whatever but are not directly cause of it.
- erschaffen: this *can* (but does not have to) imply a more creative process where something is created ("from nothing"), starting completely from scratch with no leads to start from. It can refer to both material goods or virtual ones.
- erstellen: this implies creating something, but more on the tendency of that the process or starting and end point is somewhat known (like you use 'erstellen' when creating a data plot: "Diese Grafik habe ich erstellt").

The difference between 'erschaffen' and 'erstellen' is very small and often they are and can be used as synonyms.

Comment: +1 I agree with most of this. However I see a bigger difference between "erstellen" and "erschaffen". You wouldn't say "ein Angebot erschaffen". I would argue that "erschaffen" has to imply a creative and somewhat original process, not necessarily in the sense that you create something from scratch but rather in the sense that you create something extraordinary.

Comment: I agree that it is the tendency with which these two words are used and our difference is probably only in how strong we perceive this difference to actually be:  'erschaffen' is creative, and 'erstellen' is more or less 'mechanical'. However there is a very broad transition region between and see 'erstellen' being used also in terms of 'Grafik', 'Dokument', 'Schaltplan', 'Foto' or even 'Skulptur' etc which all are or can be quite creative processes.

Comment: I'm still struggling with the explanation of the first bullet point: if this can be summarized as "participate in, but not be the only cause* I disagree and propose *also covering unintended production* instead. Nobody wants to generate exhaust, but it is difficult when having a combustion engine.

Comment: You are not the cause of the exhaust gases of your car - you are the person operating it so that the operation causes them (thus causing them indirectly). Arguably it's a hard to pin-point definition. "creating unintended" does not serve for destinction between the words either, thinking of the "Geister, die ich rief" (Zauberlehrling), "erschaffen" is the verb I'd use to describe the chaos and mayhem.

Comment: And "Ich erzeuge in der Küche ein Chaos" contradicts this of course - in that case it's directly my doing creating the chaos. So in that regard the distinction is not clear either. so... no clear-cut lines anywhere - at least none I see. (And that's why I chose "preferrably"... maybe "often" is the better choice there?)

Comment: "Ich erzeuge in der Küche ein Chaos" is a really interesting case, which I would consider a different definition of the word "erzeugen". That definition being 'leading to something'. Other examples would be "Gewalt erzeugt Gegengewalt" or "Die unklare Definition hat ein Missverständnis erzeugt".